# Asset pipeline and gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Imagine that I have a engine **gem A** that has your application.css and application.js
Those files are loaded via `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`. This works and everybody is happy.

Then comes **gem B**. That gem also has it's own css/js that it wants **gem A** to use. So it injects it into the header of **gem A** like so `stylesheet_link_tag('gem_b')`. Works fine in development but blows up when trying to deploy with `AssetNotPrecompiled` exception.

So what kind of solution do I have?

I can use `config.assets.precompile` on the main app. That's what I do now, but this really sucks.

Is there a way to inject into **gem A** application.css manifest somehow? That would be optimal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the idea is to always to only link application.js/css manifests. So you can't safely use `stylesheet_link_tag('engine_a')` but you can totally do `stylesheet_link_tag('engine_a/application')`.